# Warning: Label(s) may have changed with breqn

Tags: cross-referencing, breqn

In a document I am preparing I make extensive use of the `breqn` package.  However, this seems to cause a problem when I attempt to use math inside of captions.  An MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openright,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Equation breaking
\usepackage{breqn}

% Add support for automatic equation breaking
\gdef\wrap@breqn@environ#1#2{
    \expandafter\let\csname 
    breqn@oldbegin@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\csname 
    breqn@oldend@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\gdef\csname breqn@begin@#1\endcsname{%
        \expandafter\let\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
        breqn@oldbegin@#1\endcsname%
        \begin{#2}%
        }
        \expandafter\gdef\csname breqn@end@#1\endcsname{%
            \expandafter\let\csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
            breqn@oldend@#1\endcsname%
        \end{#2}%
        \expandafter\let\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
        breqn@begin@#1\endcsname%
        \expandafter\let\csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
        breqn@end@#1\endcsname%
    }
    \expandafter\let\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
    breqn@begin@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname 
    breqn@end@#1\endcsname
}
\wrap@breqn@environ{equation}{dmath}
\wrap@breqn@environ{equation*}{dmath*}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`_=12
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
    \mathcode`_="8000
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`_=12 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}
  Foo
  \caption{\label{fig:sumrcpint}Graphical illustration of how  $\sum_{r = m +1}^n r^{-k} < \int_{m}^{\infty} r^{-k} d r$.}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

which seems to perpetually generate a warning that the labels may have changed.  However, the .aux file remains unchanged.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've raised, i.e., I can't seem to get a warning about labels having changed. Which TeX distribution, and which version of `breqn`, do you use? (I have MacTeX2016 on my system.)

Comment: @Mico: TexLive 2015 through MacTex.

Comment: Thanks for providing this piece of information. I trust @egreg's solution has solved the issue, right?

Comment: @Micro: Yes, although I still have not been able to test with TexLive 2016 to see if it works out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{$a^b$\label{foo}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the issue disappears if `article` is used, instead of `memoir`.

Solution: add also

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`^=12 }%
```

to your setting above:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{% <-- add this
    \catcode`_=12
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
    \mathcode`_="8000
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`_=12 }% <-- add this
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`^=12 }% <-- add this
}
\makeatother
```